# Regression form - which way round

Tags: regression, terminology

The phrasing of regressions confuses me, but I'm aware of how to do it in general. Could you clarify as to whether the log of imports or GDP is the Y variable in $Y=a+bX+u$.

The task is as follows:

> Perform  a regression  of  the  logarithm  of  imports on a constant
>   and the  logarithm  of  GDP.

A rather basic question I'm sure for here, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "on a constant" part gives it away.  It must be:

$$ \log(\text{imports}) \approx a + b \log(\text{GDP}) $$

The general terminology is "regress $y$ on $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$".